# angular js - multiple ajax call fire when using angular js directive fires on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to validate my email address for uniqueness.

With a traditional method, what happens is on every key press the `$http` service is being called and lots of database calls are being fired because of this.
I want to make it an on blur event.

I wrote a script and it's working fine but when I test it for the blur event it still fires the `$http` service several times. By several times; let's suppose the ajax call already fires for the first time, upon the next go 2 calls will be caught in **firebug**, and this happens again for the next go making a total of 3 extra calls. This makes 6 calls for every 3.

```
elem.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
   elem.on('blur', function(){                  
       bindData();
       scope.$apply(function () {
         ctrl.$setViewValue(elem.val());
       });
   });
```

The plunker of the code is here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/kR9v91nV2uTkuTtwgX6p?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the code in your example

```
elem.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');
            elem.on('blur', function(){
              // on blur ajax call will fire
                bindData();
                scope.$apply(function () {
                          ctrl.$setViewValue(elem.val());
                    });
            });
```

seems to show that you're writing AngularJS code in jQuery way. This is not how it's designed to be used, please take a look at this remarkable post - ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

For your case main requirement - **to decrease amount of server calls by debouncing model changes** - there is a specific AngularJS model property [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions). Utilizing this your `<input>` tag code will look like this:

```
<input ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 } } /*other attributes*/ />
```